# JPanel changes its position by itself

Tags: java, swing

I create a HashMap<String, Panel> via a method and return it to use, but one Panel(JPanel) element changes its coordinates to x0 y0 even though I don't, is this a compiler error or my code?

I checked the objects during their creation, but the problem is not in the method that creates

Main class:

```
private static boolean initialization() {
        Window mainWindow = new Window(PROGRAM_NAME, true, -1, -1, WINDOW_MAIN_WIDTH, WINDOW_MAIN_HEIGHT);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setResize(false);
        int[] size = {
                100,
                100,
                100,
                100
        };
        Color[] colors = {
                Color.RED,
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.YELLOW,
                Color.ORANGE,
                Color.CYAN
        };
        mainWindow.setPanels(WindowPanels.createPanels(size, colors, mainWindow));

        System.out.println(mainWindow.getPanel("down").getLocation());
        
        Label l = new Label("Test", 0, 0);
        l.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mainWindow.addCom(l, "left");
        
        l = new Label("Test", 0, 0);
        l.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mainWindow.addCom(l, "top");
        
        l = new Label("Test", 0, 0);
        l.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mainWindow.addCom(l, "right");
        
        l = new Label("Test", 0, 0);
        l.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mainWindow.addCom(l, "down");
        
        l = new Label("Test", 0, 0);
        l.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mainWindow.addCom(l, "head");
        
        System.out.println(mainWindow.getPanel("down").getLocation());
        
        windows.add(mainWindow);
        
        return true;
    }
```

Class with method for create:

```
public class WindowPanels {

    public static HashMap<String, Panel> createPanels(int[] size, Color[] color, Window window){
        HashMap<String, Panel> panels = new HashMap<String, Panel>();
        
        int winWidth = window.getWidth(), winHeight = window.getHeight();
        int x = 0, y = 0, width = winWidth, height = winHeight;
        
        if (size[0] > 0) {
            x = 0;
            y = size[1];
            width = size[0];
            height = winHeight - size[1] - size[3];
            panels.put("left", new Panel(color[0], x, y, width, height));
        } else size[0] = 0;

        if (size[1] > 0) {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            width = winWidth;
            height = size[1];
            panels.put("top", new Panel(color[1], x, y, width, height));
        } else size[1] = 0;

        if (size[2] > 0) {
            x = winWidth - size[2];
            y = size[1];
            width = size[2];
            height = winHeight - size[1] - size[3];
            panels.put("right", new Panel(color[2], x, y, width, height));
        } else size[2] = 0;

        if (size[3] > 0) {
            x = 0;
            y = winHeight - size[3];
            width = winWidth;
            height = size[3];
            panels.put("down", new Panel(color[3], x, y, width, height));
        } else size[3] = 0;
        
        x = size[0];
        y = size[1];
        width = winWidth - size[0] - size[2];
        height = winHeight - size[1] - size[3];
        panels.put("head", new Panel(color[4], x, y, width, height));
        
        return panels;
    }
    
}
```

From class Panel (extends JPanel)

```
public Panel(Color colorBackground, LayoutManager layout, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(layout);
        setBackground(colorBackground);
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }
```

even if I do this:

```
System.out.println(mainWindow.getPanel("down").getLocation());
System.out.println(mainWindow.getPanel("down").getLocation());
```

it will return different values

[Full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wK3WoCVKYov9mfbfk2F1eBKOkVj3Unb-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [mcve] please.. that said: __never-ever- do any manual sizing or locating of components, that's the exclusive job of a layoutManager! unrelated: don't name custom classes the same as core classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You badly need to use a LayoutManager. It is a class designed to keep your components at the correct size and position, even if windows or content need a resize.

Check this nice [Oracle tutorial on Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: If I have to use absolute positions and sizes, don't I need to create multiple panels? LayoutManager destroys the use of absolute so I did so

Comment: If you believe that's what you need go for it. But on this site the pattern is censored.

Comment: _I have to use absolute positions and sizes_ there's no need to - if you feel you need it, you are most probably doing something utterly wrong ;)

Comment: _this site the pattern is censored_ it's simply plain wrong, and nobody wants to spread incorrect approaches :)